# How to Convert a String into StringVar() in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, tkinter

here i have a list containing n string values

```
    str = ['var1','var2','var3',...]
    variable = StringVar(str[0])
    variable.set('hello world')
```

I want to convert the all string values in the list  into `String Var()`
This program shows error like str object has no object _root

I tried in may ways but I can't

thanks in advance for answers...!!

Comment: It is `variable = StringVar(value=str[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create root window before defining strVars.
Try like this:

```
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()

strs = ['var1','var2','var3']

strvars = []
for s in strs:
   strvar = tkinter.StringVar(value=s)
   strvars.append(strvar)

print(strvars)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()
variable = StringVar(root)
for st_r in ['var1','var2','var3',...]:
 variable.set(st_r)
root.mainloop()
```

Update:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
variable = tk.StringVar(root)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=variable).grid(row=0, column=3)
for st_r in ['var1','var2','var3',...]:
 variable.set(st_r)
 root.update()
 input()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What the point of the for loop because the result is the same as setting the last item in the list to `variable`?

Comment: I don't understand well your comment, but I have updated my answer. 
hope it be as you ask. 
thank for commenting

Comment: I mean that the final result of the for loop is the same as `variable.set(["var1", ...][-1])`.